# Trouble with break point in visual studio for mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I am using visual studio for mac 2019, when I run my application Xamarin in Android the breakpoints are disabled, I don't know why because in other files yes it works excelent the breakpoints, can help me?[the file I am working Is mockdatastore.cs en Xamarín project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzid6.jpg)

Comment: Hi, could the breakpoints work fine with other files in your project? What's the version of the VS? Try to update it the lastest stable version and test agian. Here is a similar issue case, you could refer to: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/breakpoint-not-hitting-in-visual-studio-for-mac-20/942115

Answer (score 0):

I already checked and version of my VS Is 8.9.4 and it already have the last versión, also I did the same the link You shared me!! But same not Work the breakpoints.

Comment: Could the breakpoints work fine with other files in your project? Does the problem only occur in the mockdatastore.cs file?

Comment: Yes, in other files working fine! but today I was doing some tests and I discovered  in other project Xamarín AND I happen the same case but It's enable the breakpoint, I thing my code have  some problem and then the breakpoints Is disabled.

Comment: Could the project deploy well?

Comment: Yes, the project deploys well but I think my code Is the problem!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details about the issue. Try to get the cause to the code.